# How to run tflite model on Coral CPU

Tags: google-coral

Is it really possible to run the tflite model on Coral CPU?

Coral docs for `BasicEngine` states: `model must be compiled for the Edge TPU; otherwise, it simply executes on the host CPU.` [Coral doc](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/reference/edgetpu.basic.basic_engine/)

I've tried to run Keras Mobilenet converted to tflite and intentionally not compiled for Edge-tpu but got the following error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "estimate.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "estimate.py", line 42, in main
    engine = BasicEngine(args.model)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 300, in __init__
    this = _edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.new_BasicEngine(*args)
RuntimeError: Error in interpreter initialization.
```

Comment: did you solved it? I'm having same issue

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna, no, didn't work on this issue yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can. Basically, any unsupported operation that is run in your model automatically runs on the CPU. See [this image](https://coral.ai/static/docs/images/edgetpu/compile-tflite-to-edgetpu.png) for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your converted model inputs and outputs are quantized to UINT8.
Otherwise it happens even after you compile the model.